# Fatal Error when renewing membership after Upgrading to 4.6.16

Tags: civimember

Since upgrade, I am not able to renew membership from backend. As soon I press RENEW I am getting this Fatal Error message:

`2016/05/13 11:57:55 [error] 8711#0: *2228 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/utils.php on line 1408" while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.59.126.181, server: demo.com, request: "POST /civicrm/contact/view/membership HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/demo.com.sock:", host: "demo.com", referrer: "https://demo.com/civicrm/contact/view/membership?action=renew&reset=1&cid=398&id=52&context=membership&selectedChild=member"`

Can anyone help please? how to fix this?

Comment: Are you on PHP 5.6?

Comment: I am using  PHP 5.5

Comment: Did you upgrade from 4.6.15 -> 4.6.16?

Comment: No, I have upgraded from 4.6.14

Comment: Ok - good. I will have a look - this AM - and get back to you

Comment: is there a to go back to 4.6.14?

Comment: Easier to fix this than to have to restore from backup and then re-add (contact edits, contributions) everything that happened between your upgrades; easier to just hold off on renew via backend for a few hours. If I can reproduce it - I'll look into it

Comment: Ok, I will wait for you, Its actually not only renew membership, but other stuff as well, thats why I am worried., please look here http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11797/keep-getting-http-error-500-since-upgraded-to-4-6-16

Comment: In that case restoring from backup may be your best option. I do have your backtrace here so will still look at this piece this AM

Comment: Thanks. If I restore from backup, people who have signed up new membership or contribution online, would I be able to revert them back? specially recurring contributions? Or I have to do it manually?

Comment: Can I just not replace the old codebase? Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a conflicting extension was causing the problem. ***CiviRules***. Once that is uninstalled everything seems to be working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

@Tapash - I just tried to reproduce this on one of our live 4.6.16 projects and I can not.

From a Contact's Membership I'm successfully able to both:

- more -> Renew [no errors; renewed properly] &
- more -> Renew-Credit Card [no errors; made payment; got receipt; renewed properly]

I've also checked the JIRA issues and I don't see anyone else describing what you're observing. Considering your other Q as well - I'm wondering if perhaps something went wrong during your recent upgrade?

General recipe for this is to restore both code base (files) & databases back to 4.6.14 and then to run the upgrade script [to 4.6.16] again. If you can: run it via drush - it may give you some warnings/errors that give you some insight as to what's going on.

> sudo -u apache drush civicrm-upgrade-db