# Keep getting HTTP ERROR 500 since upgraded to 4.6.16

Tags: civievent, civimember

Since I have upgraded to 4.6.14 > 4.6.16 everything is so messed up on my website. Events that are not yet finished they are not appearing on the dashboard, Cant change the event end date, clicking save button returns only endless CiviCRM logo loop. Cant renew membership. Keep getting the message "The Contact Sub Type does not match the Contact type for this record".

Comment: Could you paste the errors you're getting in the error log?

Comment: Also, did you back up your site before upgrading?  It might be best to just revert to that.

Comment: Yes, I have kept a backup, but the complication arises due to entries we have made after upgrade. then all new entries have to be made manually? I was thinking, what would be complication if I use database version 4.6.16 but codebase 4.6.14? I have tried that on a demo install and all worked fine!!

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK, you would have to make the new entries manually.  But it looks like from your other post you've gotten everything figured out.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

@Tapash - I tried to reproduce one of the specific issues that you reported post upgrade to 4.6.16 : [Fatal Error when renewing membership after Upgrading to 4.6.16](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11796/fatal-error-when-renewing-membership-after-upgrading-to-4-6-16/11798#11798)

But I can not - it's all working fine on our 4.6.16s - I also don't have any reports of any of our projects experiencing issues on 4.6.16 I'm wondering if perhaps something went wrong during your recent upgrade?

General recipe for this is to restore both code base (files) & databases back to 4.6.14 and then to run the upgrade script [to 4.6.16] again. If you can: run it via drush - it may give you some warnings/errors that give you some insight as to what's going on.

> sudo -u apache drush civicrm-upgrade-db

Answer (score 0):

6.18 which is out now. There were regressions in 4.6.16 which had fixes in 4.6.17 & 4.6.18 due to fixing a difficult security issue